# How to submit a mock url?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a problem, I can't test my forms by using requests.

```
add_playlist = self.client.post(reverse('new-playlist'),
                                    data={'url': 'https://dailyiptvlist.com/dl/it-m3uplaylist-2018-03-11-1.m3u'})
```

I need to create a mock response for `'https://dailyiptvlist.com/dl/fr-m3uplaylist-2018-03-06.m3u'` so it will be acceptable to test adding a channel while the url isn't maintained. So, I need to create a mock response for this url. I can't imagine how to do this. Please help me.

Comment: This is far too vague. What is this doing and what is going wrong?

Comment: Ok, generally I need to test forms by using post requests. But the url in tests can be not maintained anymore so I need to provide a clear way to not every time change the url. I can't just always write a new url if the last one was deprecated. I know I need to use mock response but I don't understand how to do this. I don't need to load channel to server, only url.

Comment: I think you need to show the code under test, as well as the rest of the test case.

Comment: @personality13 does my answer helped you?

Comment: Yeah! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could give a try to this library (`responses` see https://github.com/getsentry/responses) allowing you to test arbitrary requests scenarios with mocked responses.

Idea is simply:

- you hardcode the desired response in some dict
- you create mock of the certain url so the real request does not go somewhere in the web, but uses the mocked data and provided status code etc. what you configured using `responses.add` and it is valid in the scope of decorated method with `@responses.activate`

Example test - which is testing either my method `reverse_geocoding(latitude, longitude)` extract desired thing from the whole response it gets from Google Maps API:

```
import json
import responses

from django.conf import settings
from django.test import TestCase

from utils.geocoding import reverse_geocoding, REVERSE_GEOCODING_URL


RESPONSE_GEOCODING_MOCK = {
    'results': [
        {
            'address_components': [
                {'long_name': '74', 'short_name': '74', 'types': ['street_number']},
                {'long_name': 'Mickiewicza', 'short_name': 'Mickiewicza', 'types': ['route']},
                {'long_name': 'Żoliborz', 'short_name': 'Żoliborz', 'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_1']},
                {'long_name': 'Warszawa', 'short_name': 'Warszawa', 'types': ['locality', 'political']},
                {'long_name': 'Warszawa', 'short_name': 'Warszawa', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
                {'long_name': 'mazowieckie', 'short_name': 'mazowieckie', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
                {'long_name': 'Poland', 'short_name': 'PL', 'types': ['country', 'political']}
            ],
            'formatted_address': 'Mickiewicza 74, Warszawa, Poland',
            'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 52.2790223, 'lng': 20.980648},
                         'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
                         'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 52.2803712802915, 'lng': 20.9819969802915},
                                      'southwest': {'lat': 52.2776733197085, 'lng': 20.9792990197085}}
                         },
            'place_id': 'ChIJxXoMrOfLHkcRBAFsrjKGcMc',
            'types': ['street_address']
        }
    ],
    'status': 'OK'
}


class TestGoogleAPIGeocodingConsumer(TestCase):

    @responses.activate
    def test_geocoding(self):
        latitude, longitude = 52.27904, 20.980366
        responses.add(
            responses.GET,
            REVERSE_GEOCODING_URL.format(
                latitude=latitude,
                longitude=longitude,
                api_key=settings.GOOGLE_API_KEY
            ),
            body=json.dumps(RESPONSE_GEOCODING_MOCK),
            content_type="application/json")

        response = reverse_geocoding(latitude, longitude)
        self.assertEqual(response, {'address_city': 'Warszawa',
                                    'address_country': 'Poland',
                                    'address_number': '74',
                                    'address_street': 'Mickiewicza'})
```

the tested method for reference:

```
import requests
REVERSE_GEOCODING_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={latitude},{longitude}&key={api_key}"


def reverse_geocoding(latitude, longitude):

    url = REVERSE_GEOCODING_URL.format(
        latitude=latitude,
        longitude=longitude,
        api_key=settings.GOOGLE_API_KEY
    )
    response = requests.get(url)
    info = response.json()
    address = {}

    for component in info['results'][0]['address_components']:
        if 'street_number' in component.get('types'):
            address['address_number'] = component['long_name']
        if 'route' in component.get('types'):
            address['address_street'] = component['long_name']
        if 'locality' in component.get('types'):
            address['address_city'] = component['long_name']
        if 'country' in component.get('types'):
            address['address_country'] = component['long_name']

    return address
```